# Extra clases in asmx soap webservice

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, asmx

I've make my own asmx webservice using c#. My main class looks like this

```
[WebService(Namespace = "my.namespace")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[SoapDocumentService(SoapBindingUse.Literal, SoapParameterStyle.Bare, RoutingStyle = SoapServiceRoutingStyle.RequestElement)]
public class ICService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod()]
    public ProductListResponse GetProductList(ProductListRequest ProductListRequest) { ... }

}
```

If I look at the xml request for this method on the web this is the result:

```
<soap:Body>
  <ProductListRequest xmlns="my.namespace">
    . . .
  </ProductListRequest>
</soap:Body>
```

Everithing works fine, but when I add a reference to this WS in any other proyect I need extra clases for method calls. Is not a big issue but I'd like to know why this is happening.

Call example:

```
GetProductListResponse resp = client.GetProductList(new GetProductListRequest
{
    ProductListRequest = new ProductListRequest { }
});
```

Where does this **GetProductListRequest** class come from? Anwser seems to have extra classes: GetProductListResponse.GetProductListResult.Products instead of just ProductListResponse.Products.

I've use many other webservices but this behaviour is new for me.

Answer (score 2):

When you add a reference to a SOAP web service, Visual Studio can generate message contract. It is a class that will wrap all the method parameter. It is usefull when the service is updated and a new parameter is added.

If you don't want these message contract, you can uncheck it in the advanced settings when you add the reference. You can also access this form by right clicking on the service reference then choose *Configure Service Reference*.

[image]

You can also decorate `ProductListRequest` with the `[MessageContract]` attribute and Visual Studio will use this type instead of creating a new one

You can find more information about message contract on the official documentation : [Using Message Contracts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-message-contracts)

Comment: I've tried to check that but result is the same. About [MessageContract], do I need any dll? Can't find it